# iOS itms-service not working, not able to install the app via safari

Tags: ios

I'm trying to install the iOS application via Safari.
When archiving the IPA file I have checked in Over Air installation and entered the right URL for ipa, 57x57, 512x512 images. Then created Manifest Plist file.

And I'm calling the Manifest file using the below URL

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=MANIFEST_SERVER_URL
```

While trying to open the link, It shows Open in iTunes correctly, but nothing happens for some time.

Then I get this alert "**Cannot connect to URL**".

Why is this happening? Is this because we are using self signed certificate in our server. If yes how to resolve it without buying the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You need a valid HTTPS cert to use this.

You can

- get a free cert at letsencrypt.org
- upload your app to DropBox or other file sharing service that provides an HTTPS URL
- distribute build via distribution service like hockeyapp or TestFlight

Comment: It seems like dropbox also not working. After Open in iTunes alert nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with, https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/public-folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS 11 with a self-signed certificate. But it works fine on iOS 13.
After searching around, I finally got a workaround:

Go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings. Under "Enable full trust for root certificates", turn on trust for the certificate.

[Official document](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204477)